# Android TV forces app in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation, android-tv

I have an Android mobile app and now I'm trying to run it on Android TV emulator, but it doesn't respond to screen orientation, it is always in portrait mode even though I handled it in code (it0s working both on mobile and tablet).. This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="------">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />

<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="-----"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_2"
    android:label="@string/app_nameMain"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:label">

<activity
    android:name=".activities.LauncherActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Translucent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".activities.LogInActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
<activity
    android:name=".activities.BrowserManagerActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/MyHomeCustomTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

</application>
```

I also tried adding this line of code but it's not helping:

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
android:required="false" />
```

Did you have similar experience or do you have any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for particular activity ?

Comment: It would be a problem for my phone and tablet app since they both use the same activity both in portrait and landscape

Comment: It is best if you want your same application to work on TV and Phones/Tablets, is to include a separate Activity that is targeted for leanback devices.   This way when running on an Android TV device the appropriate launcher is picked up.  You'll need to add the appropriate category and launcher intent filters.  As well as the banner attribute.  See the declaring activity section of the Android TV Leanback docs.

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html

Comment: You should probably also add an intent for the LEANBACK_LAUNCHER category. Also, are there any types of components in your themes that would force portrait?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not about your application orientation configurations. Many Android-tv producers force the orientation as landscape. If you have access, you may check system properties and find about `x.forceorientation:landscape` and change it.

Some producers have also put a settings menu option such as **System Settings > Display > Rotate**.

Another way, [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&hl=en) application can work on some devices

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with a real TV device - the system ignored rotation at all (everything worked fine on tablets and phones).
I found solution for my case but it can be inappropriate for you.
So, the short answer is "impossible" the long answer goes here:

Firmware for TV devices often tweaked by their manufacturers, in my case it was **/system/framework/services.jar**
that contained **services\com\android\server\wm\WindowManagerService.java**
in which the following code handled the rotation case:

```
if ("box".equals(SystemProperties.get("ro.target.product", "tablet"))) {
    rotation = 0;
}
```

of course the **/system/build.prop** has setting **ro.target.product=box**, when I tried to patch this file (I had root and possibility to reflash firmware) the system went into the kind of boot loop. The parameter **ro.target.product** was used several times inside system applications so I think that final firmware in my case lacks some additional code to handle other target modes. Because of this I was forced to patch **classes.dex** directly in order to turn this checking off.

Another set of options that controls rotation are **persist.demo.hdmirotates** and **persist.demo.hdmirotation**, by default they were turned off. When I added them via the command line:

```
setprop persist.demo.hdmirotates true
setprop persist.demo.hdmirotation landscape
```

I got desired behavior: my application chooses necessary orientation and it works! In my case the rotation of TV depends upon cabling requirements, i.e. the relative position of TV and its corresponding socket outlet on the wall.

So, no free lunch :-( each device should be handled separately.

Comment: i tried this but it shows setprop persist.demo.hdmirotates  not found