# Not able to switch to portrait mode on android tv (android version 9.0)

Tags: android, android-tv

Changing screen orientation preference in the Android Manifest to Portrait does not open activity in portrait mode on androidtv V9.0.

Adding programmatically setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
does not switch the activity orientation to portrait mode on androidtv V9.0

Both of above are working on my mobile device android Version 9.0. But when I open same app on andoridtv activity is opened in landscape mode only.

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187732/android-tv-forces-app-in-portrait-mode)?

Comment: Yes, But there is no rotate option in Display menu.

Comment: I found this on the web in a comment: Android v7+ has removed the ability for Android TVs to be set in portrait mode. I hope it is not true and if somebody does have a solution then I'm really appreciating!